# Why is my installer searching for another, non-existent MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-installer

My installer has recently started crashing during an upgrade. Just after laying down files, it displays a box saying:

> A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file:
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\2\MyInstaller.msi

I am sure this error is correct because we have never shipped an file `MyInstaller.msi`. I ship `Package.msi`, bootstrap it with a custom bootstrapper as `MyInstaller.exe` and then, using `MyInstaller.exe` call `msiexec /i Package.msi`.

This has been working perfectly until very recently when `Package.msi` started failing while apparently trying to look for `MyInstaller.msi`. Why would it do that? Wilogutl.exe only says "A standard or custom action appears to have failed." which isn't very helpful.

I'm still not sure why this is happening but I found a possibly-relevant log section:

> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:868]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Specifed source is already in a list.
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Machine policy value 'DisableBrowse' is 0
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownBrowse' is 0
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Adding new sources is allowed.
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Package name retrieved from configuration data: 'MyInstaller.msi'
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:869]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:871]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:871]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
>
> MSI (c) (D0:54) [09:03:23:871]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0

Another oddity: Add/Remove Programs shows that the older version is installed and my binaries confirm that. However, if I try to run the MSI for the new version directly, I receive the error message:

> Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of
> this version cannot continue...

I often get this error message when, during my development process, I try to install an MSI with the same version but different package codes. However, Orca says the new MSI is definitely a higher version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under circumstances unknown to myself, windows caches the file name of the MSI used to install the product initially. So when I run an older version, my bootstrapper unloads the MSI as `MyInstaller.msi`, and installs my product.

I recently changed the bootstrapper to unload it as `Package.msi`. Now, under these mysterious conditions, windows caches the file name as `MyInstaller.msi` and, in the middle of running `Package.msi` attempts to refer back to `MyInstaller.msi` which no longer exists.

I don't know why it's doing this or how to make it stop but I've reverted my change and am again unloading my MSI from the bootstrapper as `MyInstaller.msi`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last comment about same version but different package code, the version may be somewhat irrelevant. ProductCode is what defines that a product is already installed, so attempting to install something else with the same ProductCode (but a different version) will result in that message. PackageCode matters, but most tools simply generate a new one at every build so it's not usually an issue. So if you are really doing an upgrade you should have a WiX major upgrade element and a new ProductCode AND ProductVersion increment somewhere in the first three fields.

If this is on a client system, could they have installed that other product? Do you install any fairly common items (maybe from merge modules) that may be shared with other products? For example, if you were to install a commonly shared file (Crystal Reports, C++ Dlls etc) with a Component ID that breaks sharing then you might trigger Windows to try to resolve the sharing version issue by going to another MSI file. Incidentally, this can be a common problem when MSI installs use "version lying" when the file actually being installed has a version that is not the same as the one in the File Table of the MSI file. Also, look at the Windows Event Log, Application, MsiInstaller entries because there is probably an entry with a Component ID listed as the trigger for a repair and getting a file from its containing product MSI file.

Just to make things even more confusing, a DisableMSI policy of 1 blocks some installs (see the docs).

Comment: Hi Phil, unfortunately, I still don't know what the problem is but I've found how to solve it. When I said 'upgrade', I meant a minor one. The two packages do have identical product codes and major versions but we do that all the time. If you can shed any light on why windows might be caching my install name (as I described in my answer), I'll give you an upvote :)